# How to use (eigen) unaryExpr and lambda function without return values?

Tags: c++, lambda, eigen

Here is my example code:

```
using namespace Eigen;
VectorXi a = VectorXi::Random(10);
VectorXi b = VectorXi::Random(10);
VectorXi c;
c << 0, 2, 5, 7;
c.unaryExpr([&](int i) { a[i] = b[i]; }); // This will not work
c.unaryExpr([&](int i) { a[i] = b[i]; return 0; }); // This works
```

I want to copy elements from b to a using indices stored in c. Is this the correct way to use a lambda function in eigen unaryExpr ? How do I avoid the code "return 0;" since I'm not returning anything.

I'm using g++ 8.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a functional programming style to produce pure side-effects, that's not very elegant, and this is not how `unaryExpr` is supposed to be used. I would suggest a `std::vector<int>` for `c` and a for loop to make your intent clearer:

```
std::vector<int> c = {0, 2, 5, 7};
for(auto i:c) a[i] = b[i];
```

or using the head of Eigen:

```
a(c) = b(c);
```

with `c` either a `VectorXi` or a `std::vector<int>` or whatever...

Comment: what do you mean "using the head of Eigen" ? i don't think a(c) = b(c) working

Comment: I meant the devel branch, also called the default branch: [eigen_default.tar.bz2](http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/default.tar.bz2)

Comment: ah, I can not use the devel branch, but your std::vector suggestion is good enough. Thanks